# NiFi: Wait-Notify indefinite wait issue. View contents of Distributed Map Cache?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am testing a wait notify workflow as shown in the pic. I am using "${fragment.identifier}" as "Release Signal Identifier" for both WAIT and NOTIFY. "Signal Counter Name" is default/empty. "Target Signal Count" for wait is "${fragment.count}". Not sure why the WAIT is indefinitely waiting even after all the split fragments are processed and notified by NOTIFY. Please help. Is there a way to view the contents of Distributed Map Cache to identify what is going on - i.e value of signal counters etc [image: Wait Notify Workflow]

**UPDATE:**

Solved the indefinite wait issue by adding a **self-loop** on "wait" from WAIT processor onto itself as shown in the pic.  [image]

**PENDING:** Still need a way to view entries in Distributed Map Cache.

Comment: The comment on the self-loop bit helped me fix mine so thanks for that. I also had to add a FIFO prioritiser to that queue. Don't think it's well documented - with hindsight, I guess that's what this means from the docs: _"It is recommended to use a prioritizer (for instance First In First Out) when using the 'wait' relationship as a loop"_.
Not sure about how to view the cache I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the cache entries you can do this:

Configure the DistributedMapCacheServer to use a persistence directory like this:

[image]

After that you can take a look at the folder content and check what do you have in the cache.